# Access Excel workbook through ADODB - Mutiple users at same time

Tags: database, excel, vbscript, oledb, adodb

I am trying to access Excel workbook placed in a share path through ADODB connection in different remote machines. But when multiple remote machines trying to access the same Excel sheet, it thows the following error:

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

**Connection String used**:

```
strConnection_Write = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
    Runmanager_path & ";Mode= Share Deny None" & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: You can check if the file is already open before you attempt to make the connection (there are several ways to do that in vbscript.. just do a search for it). If the file is open, you can either wait or quit your script. If not, you can attempt the connection

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue a while back with OLEDB, got past it by using DAO...

```
Dim DBworkbook As DAO.Database
Dim DBSheet As DAO.Recordset

Set DBworkbook = OpenDatabase("C:\File.xls", False, False, "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;") 
Set DBSheet = DBworkbook.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]")

DBSheet.MoveFirst
Do Until DBSheet.EOF
  If DBSheet!Name = "Bob" Then
     DBSheet.Edit
     DBSheet!Addeess = "5 Something Street"
     DBSheet.Update
  End If
  DBSheet.MoveNext
Loop
```